# Не правильно работает кодировка md5

Tags: android, button, md5

У меня два вопроса: 
первый: почему-то не корректно работает кодировка, передаю в кодировку Password, полученный результат отправляю на сервер, мне же в ответ пишет что пароль не верный (пароль перепроверила)... Что я сделала не так?
второй: у меня при нажатии на кнопку зайти, конектиться на сервер только при повторном нажатии на кнопку..

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity {
public static String Login = "login";
public static String Password = "password";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.efrgtaw);
    final EditText account = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText loginIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final Button butlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Login = loginIn.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();
    butlogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Please wait, connecting to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            try {
                final String accountValue = URLEncoder.encode(account
                        .getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                final String loginValue = URLEncoder.encode(loginIn
                        .getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                String passwordStr = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText()
                        .toString(), "UTF-8");

                if ((Login != null && Login.equals(""))
                        || (Password != null && Password.equals(""))) {

                    butlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                butlogin(Password);
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }}
                        public void butlogin(String password)
                                throws IOException {
                            // Create MD5 Hash
                            MessageDigest digest = null;
                            try {
                                digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                                        .getInstance("MD5");
                            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {

                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            digest.update(password.getBytes());
                            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

                            StringBuffer MD5Hash = new StringBuffer();
                            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                                String h = Integer
                                        .toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                                while (h.length() < 2)
                                    h = "0" + h;
                                MD5Hash.append(h);
                            }
                            String URL = "https://"
                                    + accountValue
                                    + ".megaplan.ru/BumsCommonApiV01/User/authorize.api?Login="
                                    + loginValue + "&Password=" + MD5Hash;
                            Log.i("httpget", URL);

                            try {
                                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
                                HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
                                HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
                                if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                                    String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                                    Log.i("GET RESPONSE", response);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                });
            }}catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}});}}
```

Comment: Я тут подумала, скорее всего я не правильно передаю данные введенного пароля в обработку.

Answer (score 6):

1. md5 это не кодировка, а алгоритм хэширования.
2. Немного странный механизм трансформации байтового массива в строку, мне кажется алгоритм у вас необратимый, по крайней мере не представляю, как на стороне сервера из строки обратно вытащить массив байтов.

Нормальный алгоритм перекодировки массива байт в шестнадцатиричную строку обычно такой:

```
char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
   char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
   for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
       int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
       hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
       hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
   }
   return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Comment: md5 уже устарел, чем его можно заменять в текущих реалиях?

Comment: sha256 например

Answer (score 3):

Вот Вам рабочая функция, которая кодирует правильно md5 строку. Она у меня используется в проекте и точно корректно работает.

```
private final static String md5(final String s) {
    String result = new String();

    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }

        result = hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Вот почему, несмотря на все гигагерцы, проги под андроилом еле шевелятся.

Comment: avr - почему? я не совсем поняла

Comment: Потому что, для простой вещи используются слишком обобщенные подходы.

Сравните хотя бы перекодировку в HEX здесь и в ответе @Barmaley ♦

Comment: @avp, мне интересно, что же именно в моём примере может так тормозить систему?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, сам стиль максимального использования готовых компонент вместо стремления к эффективности. Остальные части наверняка такие же.

Я уже сказал с чем тут надо конкретно сравнить.

Если непонятно, то работа с методами `StringBuffer` вместо прямого доступа к элементам массивов фиксированного размера (размер MD5 хэша 128 бит == 16 байт == 32 hex).

Comment: @avp, давеча пришлось одно приложение перевести в Smali код и посмотреть, что там изнутри происходит. Так вот был приятно удивлён оптимизацией насчёт памяти. Поверьте, лучше написать код, который более понятен, чем код, который эффективен совсем немного, но для других совсем непонятен. Вполне возможно, что другому человеку придётся поддерживать это приложение.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, в общем случае, безусловно, "лучше быть здоровым и богатым, чем бедным и больным".

Непонятно, только, почему эффективный код обязательно буде непонятным? Опять же, для кого непонятным?

А в данном случае, почему Вы решили, что 2 вложенных цикла понятней одного? 

(строго по секрету, здесь `while` эквивалентен `if`, который сделал бы код понятней.)

Comment: @avp, согласен. И с замечанием по поводу if вместо while. И в целом. Но есть одно маленькое "но". Если человек работает в компании, то ему, возможно, было бы лучше просто скопировать мой код и продолжить разработку, а не разбираться с md5. Тем более, что пароль передаётся только при авторизации, а она происходит всего 1 раз. Так что необходимо смотреть конкретный случай.

Comment: @avp: @Lucky_spirit никогда не работал в системе с 8kb RAM, из которых 4kb заняты компилятором, поэтому его не интересует оптимизация, а интересует читаемость кода. За это его нельзя осуждать. А я всегда наверное, как проклятый буду оптимизировать свой код на производительность - всегда чищу циклы, убираю лишние декларации, убираю все что возможно под private и проч. проч. Хотя иногда разумом понимаю, что это лишнее, но ничего не могу поделать - 4kb надо мной будут висеть всегда...

Comment: @Lucky_spirit кстати, по поводу оптимизации: в вашем коде надо использовать не `StringBuffer`, а `StringBuilder` - он несинхронизированный и посему малька побыстрее. Ну и код: 
`while (h.length() < 2)
    h = "0" + h;`
надо бы заменить на `if(h.length() < 2) hexString.append('0');`

Comment: Каждую из сторон я поняла. Не ясно только одно, к чему стремится мне, полнейшему новичку?

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, спасибо большое за совет. В будущем я, конечно же, тоже планирую оптимизировать свой код. Но именно сейчас очень ограничен по времени и занимаюсь самообразованием.
@Imire, полнейшему новичку лучше всё же с самого начала стараться писать понятный код. Один умный человек когда-то сказал: «Преждевременная оптимизация — это корень всех бед».